# How can I get GOOGLEFINANCE to return only the historical price of a stock and not an array?

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I'm trying to figure out the cost basis of some stock that I sold last year and I can't quite get `GOOGLEFINANCE` to do what I want. The stock was purchased through a DRIP so there are about five shares that get added every quarter over a *long* period of time.

I have the settlement dates and number of shares but, before 2003, I don't have the purchase price. So, I'm trying to use the `GOOGLEFINANCE` function to figure out the price but if I write

`=GoogleFinance("GOOG", "PRICE", 3/3/2000)`

I get a 2x2 array rather than just the historical price.

Is there any way to chain `GOOGLEFINANCE` into another function that would return just the value in the lower right cell?

Comment: Visitors are advised to read [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14725/how-can-i-get-googlefinance-to-return-only-the-historical-price-of-a-stock-and-n/16000#16000), not the one that is on currently on top.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  You can however just reference the lower right cell in another cell.

so if you got back from Google:

```
A1: "Date"      B1: "Close"
A2: "3/3/2000"  B2: "55.22"
A3: "Date"      B3: "Close"
A4: "3/4/2000"  B4: "58.44"
```

Set cell C1 `=B2` and cell C2 `=B4`

and the results will be:

```
C1: 55.22
C2: 58.44
```

you could also put the query in one google doc and then reference it from another google doc if you really wanted to separete the data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I'll have to do something like have sheet 2 contain all of the data and do a vlookup to get the price into sheet 1. It'll be a lot of wasted data because the purchases were made every quarter but the timing isn't consistent enough to use `interval` to only get the data I need.

Comment: The answer from @tic is simpler than this one.

Comment: This is obviously not the right answer. See below.

Answer (score 107):

Use `=INDEX(GoogleFinance("GOOG", "price", "3/3/2000"),2,2)`. Maybe you will need to close date between parenthesis.

Comment: This answer put me on the right track. The only issue was `GOOG` was not trading in 2000. So I just needed to amend the date. e.g "3/3/2010" Thanks @tic!

Comment: this definitely works better then the chosen answer

Comment: Yeah this works. You can call a range of dates with this method and perform aggregation as if it was a QUERY function.

Comment: @spinlock, you might consider changing your accepted answer to this one.

Answer (score 8):

I found a hack that works here as well.
Use `=min(GoogleFinance("Goog", "PRICE", "3/3/2000"))`.

Answer (score 2):

```
=INDEX(GoogleFinance("USDIDR", "PRICE", F530),2,2)
```

`F530` = cell with date (formatted to date)

Answer (score 1):

```
=BDMIN(GOOGLEFINANCE("Goog"; "PRICE"; "YourStarDate";"YourEndDate");"CLOSE";
       GOOGLEFINANCE("Goog"; "PRICE"; "YourStarDate";"YourEndDate"))
```

It works for me.

**Example for the english locale**:

```
=DMIN(GOOGLEFINANCE("Goog", "PRICE", "10/10/2019","10/11/2019"),"CLOSE",
       GOOGLEFINANCE("Goog", "PRICE", "10/10/2019","10/11/2019"))
```

Comment: Welcome. Please when posting try using the english locale as well as it is widely understood.