# Remove Header from GOOGLEFINANCE query

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I want to create a graph with different stock values starting and ending at a certain day. To do that I create a table like this:

[image: Example]

Where the first column is the market and the second one is the ticker of the company. Under both of them is the name of the company combined in two cells.

Now, I want to make a call to Google Finance to get all the stock values daily since a date specified in other cell and sheet:

```
=GoogleFinance(""&A1&":"&B1; "price"; Stocks!A28; TODAY())
```

This returns X rows x 2 columns with the headers Date and Close. i.e:

[image: Example2]

What can I do to remove the header row, "Date" and "Close", from the table?

I saw [another question](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/vRZt0gHAIiI) using the function INDEX to return a value of the array, but I think it only returns one single value and is not possible to return a lot of them starting with an offset:

```
 =INDEX(GoogleFinance(""&A1&":"&B1; "price"; Stocks!A28; TODAY());2;2)
```

I also tried using FILTER or OFFSET but I don't know if they just don't work for this or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Good answer here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/16000 `=INDEX(GoogleFinance("GOOG", "price", "3/3/2000"),2,2)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try:

```
=query(GoogleFinance(""&G1&":"&H1; "price"; Stocks!A28; TODAY());"select * label Col1 '', Col2''")
```

[QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)